# Octave doesn't allow me to read correctly

Tags: octave

I am trying to read `5x^2` but octave says that it's wrong also it allows us to put `(sin(x/2))^3`

```
clc; close all; clear; 

pkg load symbolic;

syms x;
f=input("Introduce la funcion ");
diff(f,x)
```

also there is the output with both cases

case (sin(x/2))^3

```
Introduce la funcion (sin(x/2))^3
ans = (sym)

       2/x\    /x\
  3*sin |-|*cos|-|
        \2/    \2/
  ----------------
         2
```

case 5x^2

```
Introduce la funcion 5x^2
parse error:

  syntax error

>>> 5x^2
     ^

error: called from
    symbolic at line 6 column 2
```

Comment: `5x^2` is invalid syntax. You want to do `5*x^2`, which works perfectly fine

Comment: You probably use Octave from Python in some manner, but you should probably share how you use it. I'm not overly familiar with Octave, but it stand out to me that `(sin(x/2))^3` has explicit operators everywhere, while `5x^2` has an implied `*` operator.

Comment: thank you guys it was that :D